# Delphi Dynamically created ADOStoredProcedure Parameters

Tags: delphi, ado

I am doing multi threading here , so I need to create the ADOStoredProcedures dynamically for each thread (among other things)

```
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Connection:=MSSQL;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.ProcedureName:='spBW_AUFTR_KOPF;1';
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Refresh;
```

This is how I create the Procedure Dynamically . And then I just want to delete some stuff , which only requires 3 parameters .

```
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.ParamValues['@OP']:='DEL';
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.ParamValues['@AB']:=DELETE_ARRAY[i].AB;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.ParamValues['@DB_YEAR']:=DELETE_ARRAY[i].DB_YEAR;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.ExecProc;
```

Problem is since the Procedure (in MSSQL) has ca. 30 parameters, Delphi complains that the other parameters are missing . This is only happening if I create this Dynamically . By drag-n-drop Component it does not .

**Question :** is it possible to auto populate all parameters and set them to null ( I thought TADOStoredProcedure.Parameters.Refresh does it... but nope )

Thank you

**Update**

```
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Connection:=MSSQL;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.ProcedureName:='spBW_AUFTR_KOPF;1';
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Prepared:=true;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Refresh;
```

Does not help :
[NEW] BW_AUFTR_KOPF Procedure or function 'spBW_AUFTR_KOPF' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied . Am I missing something else? I tried first prepared True then Refresh , and i also tried Refresh first and the prepared true .

**Update 2**

Well as suggested fixed like this :

```
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Connection:=MSSQL;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.ProcedureName:='spBW_AUFTR_KOPF;1';
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Refresh;

          for i := 0 to spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Count-1 do
            spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Items[i].Value:=null;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that ADO object be `Prepared` before refreshing the parameter collection? It's a long time I was working with ADO, so not sure.

Comment: I tried both version . First Paramters.Refresh then Prepared. I also tried Prepared True and then Parameters.Refresh.

Comment: 30 parameters?! this is really a sign for bad design. why wont you break it into dedicated stored procedures? to your question: `Parameters.Refresh` already fetches all parameters from the server for you. to use a default value set the parameter value to `Unassigned`. to set an explicit null set it to `Null`. this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183562/tadostoredproc-and-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameter-as-default-value/47189154#47189154

Comment: I have no idea how I accept a comment as a solution :) . But thanks . As for the "bad design" part ... well you can look it like this and that . I have one Stored Procedure that itself is controlled by a Master Parameter @OP , this one controls what happens, INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,MARK etc...

Comment: `...is controlled by a Master Parameter @OP` - Yes I noticed that. well, think about a procedure in Delphi (or any other langue for that matter) that accepts 30 parameters to control different tasks. IMO, it's a mess! :) anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is :

```
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Connection:=MSSQL;
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.ProcedureName:='spBW_AUFTR_KOPF;1';
spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Refresh;

          for i := 0 to spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Count-1 do
            spBW_AUFTR_KOPF.Parameters.Items[i].Value:=null;
```